# Limit for 2 decimal after point with currency symbol in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I need to set limit for UITextField like accept only 2 decimal pointed value and added automatic currency symbol.

**For Example,**

**$23.45 - Right**

**but $45.4545 - Wrong**

**$45.4545.65 - Wrong**

**45.45 -Wrong(Currency symbol should be there-automatically added if textfield has value)**

I achieved the limit for 2 decimal point but I am not getting it with currency symbol stuck.

**Note:**

(1) Currency symbol must be added automatically while user type inside UITextField

(2) If there is no value then display placeholder value.(remove currency symbol)

(3) UITextField should be accept 1 dot and 2 decimal after that like $67.89

(4) All these condition should be possible inside UITextFieldDelegate methods. Do not use static label or something else.

**here is my code...**

```
 //MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    isEditingMode = true
    switch textField.tag {
    case tag_price_txt:
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
        formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 10

        //var newString = ""

        let aString = textField.text!
        let newStr = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "£", with: "")
        textField.text = newStr

        let nsString = newStr as NSString?
        let newString:String = (nsString?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string))!

        let expression = "^[0-9]*((\\.|,)[0-9]{0,2})?$"
        let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: expression, options: .caseInsensitive)
        let numberOfMatches: Int? = regex?.numberOfMatches(in: newString, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (newString.count)))

      if numberOfMatches != 0 {

                amountTypedString = newString
                let newString1 = "\(SymbolOfCurrency.Pound.rawValue)" +  amountTypedString
                displayAmountString = newString1
                //textField.text = newString1
                print("assigned value",displayAmountString)
                return true
          }else{
            return false
        }

        return true
}
```

[image]

After input should be like this:

[image]
Help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't be able to add currency directly into text dynamically. Not easily anyway. You would have to update caret correctly everytime while you could just display it next to the text field as a non-editable label. Add/remove currency on focus lost (on blur). Use `shouldChangeCharactersIn` only to make sure the entered number is valid.

Comment: That is okay, but if there is no any text in textfield then show placesholder else while user typing add currency symbol, Note:Textfield inside tableView.

Comment: By the way, most languages display currency symbols on the right side. English is one of the exceptions. If you think about translations to other languages, make sure you can handle their rules correctly.

Comment: Also, you don't have to use `NSRegularExpression` just to check a string matches a pattern. `newString.rangeOf(expression, options: .regularExpression) != nil` would do the same.

Comment: No that's not my answers sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let dotString = "."
    let character = "£"

    if let text = textField.text{
        if !text.contains(character){
            textField.text = "\(character) \(text)"
        }
        let isDeleteKey = string.isEmpty

        if !isDeleteKey {
            if text.contains(dotString) {
                if text.components(separatedBy: dotString)[1].count == 2 || string == "."  {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your input value in this and set the return string as output

```
extension String {
        var thousandFormatted: String {
            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            let number = numberFormatter.number(from: self) ?? 0
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    //        numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_CL")
            let string = numberFormatter.string(from: number)
            return string ?? "0.00"
        }
    }
```

Use lit like this:

```
var desiredString = inputString.thousandFormatted
```

**NOTE:**
By default, the number formatter picks the local currency symbol.
If you want to specify a fixed currency use the Locale Identifier.